# How to POST request with a param of type hash

Tags: ruby, http-post, postman

I have a ruby endpoint that takes following params:

```
params do
   requires :code, type: File
   optional :args, type: Hash
end
```

How should I pass this param 'args' of type hash with postman?
I tried passing it like: {one: "eins"}
But getting invalid_params error with postman.

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: You need to provide more info,  such as what is the response you get from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a JSON API? If so, try `{"one": "eins"}` - as all JSON object keys must be quoted.